# Key combination don't work with xmodmap?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

The `tab` key on my laptop is broken, and keyboard replacement will arrive in 1 month, life is a lot harder without `tab` key. I've replaced my `fn` key to emulate `tab` key and it work well.

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 151 = Tab'
```

I can switch between input form, bash-autocomplete on command line, etc. But key combination like `alt+fn(tab)` wouldn't work. I'm trying to switch between running application with ease.

Comment: TAB can often be generated (in terminals, anyways) by using control+i

Comment: Strangely, when I press `alt+fn` it's read as `alt+tab` on xfce. Just that there's no windows switching. I've replaced switch application key to `alt+\`` for now.